# How to set only on checkBox clicked in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-linearlayout

I am building an android application where I am creating multiple checkBox in linear layout. Below is my code

```
//Make multi leg info display to user
    for(int i = 0; i < PickerForm.GoogleAddress.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_leg_detail, null);
        TextView legName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.legName);
        TextView legPhone = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.legPhoneNumber);
        TextView legAddress = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.legAddress);
        TextView legCashToPick = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.legCashToPick);
        final CheckBox radioButtonCashToCollect = (CheckBox) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonCashToCollect);
        radioButtonCashToCollect.setTag(String.valueOf(i));        
           legLinearLayout.addView(mLinearView);
        }
```

I want there should be only one checkBox clicked at a time.

Comment: can you try radiobutton ?

Comment: but how it is possible for radio button too ?

Comment: inside radioGroup, you can check only one radioButton at a time

Comment: put radiobutton on RadioGroup

Comment: I am creating multiple xml in linear layout

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use RadioGroups, in your case. those are specifically for your case, only one checked at time.

Comment: I am creating dynamic radio button

Comment: that doesnt make any problem, just add them dynamically inside the radiogroup take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380526/how-to-add-radio-button-dynamically-as-per-the-given-number-of-counts

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioButton for this purpose.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

Comment: I am creating dynamic radio button