# How to get a specific, but changing number of radiobuttons into an activity

Tags: java, android, radiobuttonlist

I am making a simple semi-textbased adventure game.

I am trying to get a working inventory switching system.

I have a system where your (up to 14) items appear as the text of radiobuttons, but it leaves a lot of them as repetitive "You have nothing"s.

Is there anyway that I can make X radio buttons come on screen, where X is the number of items you currently have that you can switch to?

I tried creating and then adding radio buttons to the radio group (and then simply deleting the old 14 buttons I originally had), but I need a class called `Context`, and as I am new to android I don't understand what that is.

```
package com.blogspot.darokrithia.dungeonfungeon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by dtabin17 on 1/21/16.
 */
public class ItemSwitcherActivity extends AppCompatActivity{        //Used to switch items in inventory slots
    int itemType = InventoryActivity.itemToSwitch;;    // lets the class know what kind of item to switch
    RadioGroup listOfItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_switcher);
        setupItems(itemType);
    }

    public void onBackClick(View v){                //when player clicks back button
        if (v.getId() == R.id.backButton){
            Intent i = new Intent(ItemSwitcherActivity.this, InventoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);                       // goes back to inventory screen
        }
    }

    public void  setupItems(int t){                                             //gets the proper Radio buttons
        int[] equippedInventory = RoomActivity.player.getEquipment();           //here until (look bellow)
        int[] inventory = RoomActivity.player.getInventory();                   //
        ArrayList <Equipment> totalInventory = new ArrayList<>();               //Compiled list of inventory and equipped items
        listOfItems = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.inventoryList);            //The radio group displayed
        ArrayList <Equipment> listedInventory = new ArrayList<>();              //Items already listed.
                                                                                //
        for (int i = 0; i < equippedInventory.length; i++){                     //
            int ID = equippedInventory[i];                                      //
            Equipment e = new Equipment(ID);                                    //
            totalInventory.add(e);                                              //
        }                                                                       //
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){                             //
        int ID = inventory[i];                                                  //
            Equipment e = new Equipment(ID);                                    //
        totalInventory.add(e);                                                  //
        }                                                                       //here gets the players equipment into a one nice and easy to use ArrayList

        switch(t){
            case(0):
                ((RadioButton) listOfItems.getChildAt(0)).setText(totalInventory.get(0).getText());
                int r = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < (totalInventory.size()-1); i++){
                    if((totalInventory.get(i).isHelmet) && !(listedInventory.contains(RoomActivity.player.getEquipment()[0]))){
                        listedInventory.add(totalInventory.get(r));
                        ((RadioButton) listOfItems.getChildAt(i)).setText(totalInventory.get(r).getText());
                        r++;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case(1):
                //do stuff
                break;
            case(2):
                //do stuff
                break;
            case(3):
                //do stuff
                break;
            case(4):
                //do stuff
                break;
            default:
                Intent i = new Intent (ItemSwitcherActivity.this, InventoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code that you have tried so far

Comment: Worth a read, when you get a chance - [What is Context in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Comment: I just added the last working version.  I am reading the context thing.

Comment: Okay, I read the thing, but how to I use context.  What should I type if I want to make a new Radio button, and then put it in an already existing radio group

Comment: Something like `RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(getContext());`

Comment: Okay I will try that and tell you if ti works.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  It crashes loading the activity.  Because I am too lazy to upload all of my code, here is the entire project's git hub.                           https://github.com/PCHSTechClub

Comment: this is a similar question that you may find useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19380858/3329488

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add radio button dynamically as per the given number of counts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380526/how-to-add-radio-button-dynamically-as-per-the-given-number-of-counts)

Comment: These are both very useful.  This is a similar question.  Thank you