# how to control the number of options in radio_botton?

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button

I need to do an app for a QCM but for each question I want to control the number of options for example:
question 1:
option0
option1
option2
question 2:
option 0
option 1
question 3:
option 0
option1
option2
option3
the problem is how to control the number of options and radio buttons depending on the question?
java, android studio
thanks

Comment: you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380858/14007693 to add radio button dynamically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add radio button dynamically as per the given number of counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380526/how-to-add-radio-button-dynamically-as-per-the-given-number-of-counts)

Comment: hello .i figured a solution is to hide the unwanted radio buttons,thanks a lot